How do I read this output from `vim --version`?
I'm not sure how to interpret vim --version output; what do the various components mean?
Here's an example:
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.1 (2024 Jan 02, compiled May 03 2024 02:45:42)
Included patches: 1-16
Modified by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -tcl
+autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
-autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
-balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term +gettext           +num64             +textobjects
-browse            -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
++builtin_terms    +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+byte_offset       +insert_expand     -perl              +title
+channel           +ipv6              +persistent_undo   -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +popupwin          +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
-clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +vim9script
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +viminfo
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3           +virtualedit
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +visual
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +visualextra
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +vreplace
+cscope            +localmap          -ruby              +wildignore
+cursorbind        -lua               +scrollbind        +wildmenu
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +windows
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       +writebackup
+diff              +modify_fname      +sodium            -X11
+digraphs          +mouse             -sound             +xattr
-dnd               -mouseshape        +spell             -xfontset
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xim
+emacs_tags        +mouse_gpm         +statusline        -xpm
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      -xsmp
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_clipboard
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary        -xterm_save
-farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vim/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Wdate-time -g -O2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -mno-omit-leaf-frame-pointer -ffile-prefix-map=/build/vim-QkysrQ/vim-9.1.0016=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -fstack-clash-protection -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fcf-protection -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vim-QkysrQ/vim-9.1.0016=/usr/src/vim-2:9.1.0016-1ubuntu7.1 -DSYS_VIMRC_FILE=\"/etc/vim/vimrc\" -DSYS_GVIMRC_FILE=\"/etc/vim/gvimrc\" -D_REENTRANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 
Linking: gcc -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim -lm -ltinfo -lselinux -lsodium -lacl -lattr -lgpm -L/usr/lib/python3.12/config-3.12-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.12 -ldl -lm 


Please [edit] and improve your question: 1) what plugin did you install? 2) what is "weird to resolve"? This is what it looks like 3) what are the exact items you're having trouble with? 4) what's the greater problem you're trying to solve? Setting up "Vim as an IDE" is beyond the scope of a question on this site. As it's written now, I don't see how your question could be answered. I'm voting to close.

Welcome to Vim!. Maybe you have to tell us more about the issue you are facing. It could be that the :version command is not the tool to detect the origin or your problem.

This will probably lead to somebody suggesting you do apt-get install vim-gtk3 to get the HUGE version with GUI for clipboard support etc. So I might as well jump ahead and do so now.

Related question: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27434/clipboard-not-activated

@VivianDeSmedt thanks , i tried to fix the compilation error and linking error and to fix that friedrich told me to update-alternatives, and i did that , i am still trying to resolve the problem as you both suggested ;(

@Friedrich i checked the other issue you shared i hope you could sort this problem with a rather solid solution

The :version command of Vim provides information about the version of Vim you are using and unfortunately not about the plugins that you installed.
From the output of :version you can determine:

The version number of Vim (e.g. 9.1)
The patches included (e.g. 1-16)
The list of feature it has been compiled with (e.g. +cindent meaning cindent indentation logic is available, -clipboard meaning clipboard support is unavailable, -X11 meaning there are no support for X11 that is needed for gVim on Linux)
The list of vimrc file that Vim will try to load at startup (run :echo $MYVIMRC to know the one it has loaded at the end)
The compilation and link flag (useful to guess the library it needs to run properly or to which version of the external languages like Python or Lua it is linked against)


when i check the :version in vim i get the output in vim which i shared that was cli output, how can i fix the "Huge version without GUI" error, the vim --version has the similar output to :version output i have shared, can you please find a way to fix this issue?

@rwen that would be apt-get install vim-gtk3.

@Friedrich i have installed that but still i could not fix the gui error

@vivan de smedt hi , how do i remove the compilation and linking errors?

There are no errors in your output. It's just status. You don't have a GUI, it's not an error, it's a fact. You might need to update-alternatives as well. Use which vim to find out which version of Vim is started. You are starting a Vim distributed by Debian; if you compiled yourself, that's not what you're running.

I have the vim installed from apt package , i have not compiled that from source file, i only compiled python plugin
